# PHP Codeigniter + Sparks + php-activerecord how to escape before insert or update data

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpactiverecord

**I'm very new php-activerecord. Is there a way auto escape all of my post/get data before update or insert records?**

```
class User extends ActiveRecord\Model {...}

class Blog extends MY_Controller
{
    function test()
    {
        $user = User::find('last');
        $user->first_name = 'test"quot' . "es'zzz";
        $user->save();
    }
}

// inserted data
// first_name = test"quotes'zzz
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what kind of escaping you are looking for? Above first name will save without a problem, so in that sense you don't have to be scared that some SQL trickery will come up: whatever string you've put in there will be saved in the field `first_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Query Bindings](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html)

> The secondary benefit of using binds is that the values are automatically escaped, producing safer queries. You don't have to remember to manually escape data; the engine does it automatically for you.

Comment: Hi thank you for reply. But in this case I'm not using Codeigniter's activerecord, I'm using php-activerecord http://www.phpactiverecord.org/ I didn't even load Codeigniter's database library.

Comment: http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Connection#methodquery  
Bound parameters are not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you encounter any trouble? PHP-ActiveRecord is using [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)([source](https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord/blob/master/lib/Connection.php#L285-315)). So you shouldn't encounter any escaping problem, if so, feel free to open n issue on the github project page: https://github.com/kla/php-activerecord

Comment: Hi I'm already recognized the PHP-ActiveRecord is not vulnerable to SQL injection. I tested try to some inject. Now i want to know there is a existed method to auto encode htmlspecialchars for all of my results to display ?

Comment: To display? So it has nothing to do with MySQL (or PHP-ActiveRecord), just use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) for HTML-like output, json_encode of JavaScript-like output and so on and so forth.